# Uniqueness of a local certain homomorphism (Etale Cohomology and the Weil Conjecture by Freitag, Kiehl)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, etale-cohomology

(All rings in the context are presumed to be *commutative, unital* and *noetherian.*)
Let $(A,n), (B_1, m_1),$ and $(B_2, m_2)$ be local rings with their maximal ideals, $k$ a field.
For $i=1,2$ there are *local-etale* maps $a_i: A \to B_i$ and local maps $p_i: B_i \to k$.

Recall that a map $\varphi: (R, n) \to (S,m)$ between local ring is called *local* if $\varphi(n) \subset n$;
it is *local-etale* if it is *local, flat, unramified* (meaning $\varphi(n) = m$ and $R/n \to S/m$ are finite separable) and $S$ arises as a localization of a *finitely generated* $R$-algebra.

Assume there exist two local maps $\phi_1, \phi_2: B_1 \to B_2$ compatible with $a_i$ and $p_i$, i.e.
$\phi_j \circ a_1 = a_2$ and $p_2 \circ \phi_j = p_1$ for $j=1,2$.

Question: Why does this imply $\phi_1= \phi_2$?

Clearly, since $p_i$ factorizes as $B_i \to B_i/m_i \to k$ and field extensions $B_i/m_i \to k$ are always injective and so mono,
the induced maps $\overline{\phi_1}, \overline{\phi_2}: B_1/m_1 \to B_2/m_2$ between residue fields coincide due to compatibility with $p_i$.

Why does this suffice to show that $\phi_1 $ and $ \phi_2$ already coincide?
Since $a_i$ unramified, we have equality $m_i = n \cdot B_i$ of maximal ideals, but *note(!)*
that we cannot apply Nakayama lemma here to deduce from $B_1= \ker(\phi_1-\phi_2) + m_1 = \ker(\phi_1-\phi_2) + n \cdot B_1$ that $B_1= \ker(\phi_1-\phi_2)$, since $B_1$ is *not* a finite $A$-module.

Source: Etale Cohomology and the Weil Conjecture by Freitag, Kiehl, page 16, Construction of Henselian rings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"First we reduce to the case where $B_1$ is actually etale $A$-algebra."

From the definition
$$a_1: A\xrightarrow{} C_1\to S^{-1}C\simeq B_1$$
where $C_1$ is a etale A-algebra and $S$ a multiplicative closed subset of $C_1$.

Now from the remark (using quasi-finiteness and Zariski's main theorem: see paragraph after Def. 1.1 page 7) $C$ is actually a localization at $T$ of an etale $A$-algebra $D_1$ that is finite as $A$-module and $T$ a multiplicative closed subset. So we have a refined diagram

$$a_1: A\xrightarrow{\psi_1} D_1\to T^{-1}D_1 \simeq C_1\to S^{-1}C\simeq B_1.$$

Now apply the Nakayama argument to the composed maps as in your attempt $\phi_1, \phi_2: D_1\to B_2$, so we are done.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this definitely solves 
the problem. But nevertheless do you maybe also see 
a more "elementary" argument (your argument above 
uses Zariski main theorem as some kind of "deep result"
und it's quite interesting to know if the claim may
be also proved "directly" without using such "heavy
weapons")?

Answer (score 0):

Here probably another way one can also prove it without Zariski main theorem as "deep input" at least if we assume $A, B_1, B_2$ to be noetherian.

Let $i_A: A \to \widehat{A}, i_{B_i}: B_i \to \widehat{B}_i$ the canonical maps to the completions and $\widehat{a}_i : \widehat{A} \to \widehat{B}_i$ the morphisms between completions. Noetherian condition implies $\cap_i m_2^i =0$ and therefore $i_{B_2}:B_2 \to \widehat{B}_2$ is mono.

Since $a_i $ are etale, $\widehat{a}_i$ are isomorphisms and the induced maps
$\widehat{\phi}_j$ coinside, since both are $\widehat{a}_2 \circ \widehat{a}_1^{-1}$. Therefore $\widehat{\phi}_2 -\widehat{\phi}_1$ is zero morphism on $\widehat{B}_1$.

If we write a commutative diagram involving $A, B_i$ and their completions we see that $\widehat{\phi}_j \circ i_{B_1}= i_{B_2} \circ \phi_j$ and therefore we have also $ i_{B_2} \circ (\phi_2 -\phi_1)= (\widehat{\phi}_2 - \widehat{\phi}_1) \circ i_{B_1}=0$. Since $i_{B_2}$ mono, we get $\phi_2 -\phi_1=0$.